# Error showing "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'"

Tags: c++

When i run this program it get fatal error and program got stopped. **I think this problem is due to string type of may be using std::string.** because when i use char data type it was runs correctly. What is the problem kindly guide.

parcel.cpp

```
#include "Parcel.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
bool check = false;

// Constructor
Parcel::Parcel(int id, std::string senderName, std::string senderAddress, std::string receiverName, std::string receiverAddress, int weight, int fee){
    this->id = id;
    this->senderName = senderName;
    this->senderAddress = senderAddress;
    this->receiverName = receiverName;
    this->receiverAddress = receiverAddress;
    this->weight = weight;
    this->fee = fee;
};

// Destructor
Parcel::~Parcel() {
    cout << "Destructor called";
}

// Defination of setter
void Parcel::setID(int id) {
    this->id = id;
    if(id < 0) {
        cout << endl << "Error: Please write valid receipt number e.g. 0 to onward";
    }
}
void Parcel::setWeight(int weight) {
    this->weight = weight;
    if(weight < 0) {
        cout << endl << "Error: Please write valid weight e.g. above to 0 grams";
    }
}
void Parcel::setFee(int fee) {
    this->fee = fee;
    if(fee < 0) {
        cout << endl << "Error: Please write valid fee e.g. 0 to onward";
    }
}
void Parcel::setSenderName(std::string senderName) {
    this->senderName = senderName;
//  if(strlen(senderName) == 0) {
//      cout << endl << "Error: Please write sender name";
//  }
}
void Parcel::setSenderAddress(std::string senderAddress) {
    this->senderAddress = senderAddress;
//  if(senderAddress == 0) {
//      cout << endl << "Error: Please write sender address";
//  }
}
void Parcel::setReceiverName(std::string receiverName) {
    this->receiverName = receiverName;
//  if(receiverName == 0) {
//      cout << endl << "Error: Please write reciever name";
//  }
}
void Parcel::setReceiverAddress(std::string receiverAddress) {
    this->receiverAddress = receiverAddress;
//  if(receiverAddress == 0) {
//      cout << endl << "Error: Please write reciever address";
//  }
}

// Defination of getter 
int Parcel::getID() {
    return id;
}
int Parcel::getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
int Parcel::getFee() {
    return fee;
}
string Parcel::getSenderName() {
    return senderName;
}
string Parcel::getSenderAddress() {
    return senderAddress;
}
string Parcel::getReceiverName() {
    return receiverName;
}
string Parcel::getReceiverAddress() {
    return receiverAddress;
}
```

parcel.h

```
#ifndef PARCEL_H
#define PARCEL_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Parcel
{
    private:
        // Declare data members
        int id, weight, fee;
        std::string senderName, senderAddress, receiverName, receiverAddress;           
    public:
        // Setter function
        void setID(int id);
        void setWeight(int weight);
        void setFee(int fee);
        void setSenderName(std::string senderName);
        void setSenderAddress(std::string senderAddress);
        void setReceiverName(std::string receiverName);
        void setReceiverAddress(std::string receiverAddress);

        // getter function
        int getID();
        int getWeight();
        int getFee();
        std::string getSenderName();
        std::string getSenderAddress();
        std::string getReceiverName();
        std::string getReceiverAddress();

        // Constructor
        Parcel(int id, std::string senderName, std::string senderAddress, std::string receiverName, std::string receiverAddress, int weight, int fee);

        // Destructor
        ~Parcel();

    protected:
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Parcel.h"
#include <string>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;

// Data member to take input from user
int id, weight, fee;
std::string senderName, senderAddress, receiverName, receiverAddress;

// main function
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "Please enter receipt  number: ";
    cin >> id;
    cout << "Please enter sender name: ";
    cin >> senderName;
    cout << "Please enter sender address: ";
    cin >> senderAddress;
    cout << "Please enter receiver name: ";
    cin >> receiverName;
    cout << "Please enter receiver address: ";
    cin >> receiverAddress;
    cout << "Please enter parcel weight(gms): ";
    cin >> weight;
    cout << "Please enter parcel fee: ";
    cin >> fee;

    // Instance of Parcel class
    Parcel parcel(parcel.getID(), parcel.getSenderName(), parcel.getSenderAddress(), parcel.getReceiverName(), parcel.getReceiverAddress(), parcel.getWeight(), parcel.getFee());

    // Set values
    parcel.setID(id);
    parcel.setSenderName(senderName);
    parcel.setSenderAddress(senderAddress);
    parcel.setReceiverName(receiverName);
    parcel.setReceiverAddress(receiverAddress);
    parcel.setWeight(weight);
    parcel.setFee(fee);

    // Make output to show on console
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Shipment Receipt" << endl << "___________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "Receipt No.: " << parcel.getID() << endl << "Sender Name: " << parcel.getSenderName() << endl 
        << "Sender Address: " << parcel.getSenderAddress() << endl << "Receiver Name: " << parcel.getReceiverName() << endl
        << "Receiver Address: " << parcel.getReceiverAddress() << endl << "Parcel Weight: " << parcel.getWeight() << endl 
        << "Parcel Shipping Charges: " << parcel.getFee() << endl;

    // Destructor call
    parcel.~Parcel();
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the destructor?

Comment: But it's called automatically... You don't need to call it

Comment: ok i'll correct it. kindly help me to debug error.

Comment: Tip: lookup what a 'default constructor' is and use it. Or, get rid of all setXXX functions and use the current constructor (i.e. Parcel parcel(id,senderName,...) Another note: writing errors to std::cout makes them visible, but it doesn't interrupt your program in anyway so it's basically useless.

Comment: If it is incomplete code how do we know why the error (which by the way you do not state clearly) happens ? Provide a minimal verifiable complete example.

Comment: i am new in c++. can u post correct code?

Comment: its approx. complete @perencia

Comment: why this program got stopped. i doesn't understand

Comment: `Parcel parcel(parcel.getID() [...]` `parcel` is undefined here, it can't possibly compile

Comment: @bc120201817ZohaibSiddiq aproxímate complete is not a valid statement :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Unfortunately it does compile.

Comment: @Oswald not for me (VC++)

Comment: its compiled but after input all values it got stopped @Rakete1111

Comment: Then maybe VC++ is too stupid to compile it. Or too smart. g++ 4.8.3 compiles it just fine.

Comment: @Oswald Then I would say it's a feature, not a bug ;) Interesting though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Parcel parcel(parcel.getID(), parcel.getSenderName(), parcel.getSenderAddress(), parcel.getReceiverName(), parcel.getReceiverAddress(), parcel.getWeight(), parcel.getFee());`

Don't do that. You are calling `parcel.getSenderName()` before the `parcel` object is fully initialized.

Comment: how can fully initialize before call parcel.getSenderName()

Comment: Pass `id`, `senderName`, `senderAdress` as arguments, instead of `parcel.getID()`, `parcel.getSenderName()`, `parcel.getSenderAddress()` etc.

Comment: Instead of asking question after question, carefully read the comments/answers, I gave the answer  already.

Comment: I am new one in c++. if i understand all thing already then no need to come on stackoverflow. please don't mind. @stijn

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't terminate with instance of bad alloc  when I tried to run. However, it does get warnings because of this line

`Parcel parcel(parcel.getID(), parcel.getSenderName(), parcel.getSenderAddress(), parcel.getReceiverName(), parcel.getReceiverAddress(), parcel.getWeight(), parcel.getFee());`

You should consider a default constructor `Parcel()` with default values assigned to different attributes and then `Parcel parcel` before assigning them in `main()`

What arguments did you run your program with?

Answer (score 1):

Your construction,

```
 Parcel parcel(parcel.getID(), parcel.getSenderName(), parcel.getSenderAddress(), parcel.getReceiverName(), parcel.getReceiverAddress(), parcel.getWeight(), parcel.getFee());
```

initialises `parcel` with itself, which is uninitialised.
This is undefined, and anything can happen.

You've already read all parameters from the user, so use them:

```
Parcel parcel(id, senderName, senderAddress, receiverName, receiverAddress, weight, fee);
```

You can remove the entire sequence of setters.

And you should not call the destructor; C++ handles destruction automatically.
If you found that idea in a book, throw it away immediately and look for a better one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).
If you don't have a book, look in the same place.